# Issue with OAuthhandler with Tweepy in Python

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

```
import tweepy as tw
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler

# your Twitter API key and API secret
my_api_key = "*****"
my_api_secret = "*****"

# authenticate
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(my_api_key, my_api_secret)
```

Error with line 2 -  if I keep this line, it gives `ImportError: No module named auth`
Error -
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'` (without using line 2)

Please help! This must be really simple, but doesn't work!

Comment: Docs seem to suggest its found under the main module https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/getting_started.html Remove `from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there's no other files or folders in your path called `tweepy`.
You're likely importing a module other than the Tweepy library.